# Manage my query results according to some conditions

Tags: mysql, sql

I have this 2 tables in a MySQL database:

```
CREATE TABLE transaction (
   ID_TRANSACTION bigint(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
   DS_STATUS varchar(20) NOT NULL,
   INSERTED_AT timestamp(3) NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(3),
   UPDATED _AT timestamp(3) NULL DEFAULT NULL ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(3),
   PRIMARY KEY (ID_TRANSACTION)
 ) ENGINE=InnoDB; 
 
CREATE TABLE transaction_log (
   ID_TRANSACTION_LOG bigint(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
   ID_TRANSACTION bigint(20) NOT NULL,
   DS_STATUS varchar(20) NOT NULL  COMMENT '(New, Approved, Rejected, Error).',
   INSERTED_AT timestamp(3) NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(3),
   PRIMARY KEY (ID_TRANSACTION_LOG ),
   KEY idx_1 (ID_TRANSACTION),
   CONSTRAINT fk_1 FOREIGN KEY (ID_TRANSACTION) REFERENCES transaction (ID_TRANSACTION) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION
 ) ENGINE=InnoDB;
```

Basicly, in transaction_status_history i will have one or more records for the same ID_TRANSACTION.

Based on this simple query below, i want to put some conditions to different cases:

Simple query:

```
Select DS_STATUS from transaction_LOG where id_transaction = 12;
```

If i have for this query a row with DS_STATUS = 'New' and another row with DS_STATUS = 'Approve'
my query have to return the ID_TRANSACTION_LOG from the row with DS_STATUS = 'New'.

If i have for this query a row with DS_STATUS = 'Rejected' and another row with DS_STATUS = 'New'
my query have to return the ID_TRANSACTION_LOG from both records.

How can i do this logic in a single query?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you left join the table to itself, you can check for the 'Approved' IND_STATUS. You can make a few further logical assumptions, like we'll always return the 'New' record and we always want to return 'Rejected' if it exists. Unless you have more business requirements you haven't told us, you can accomplish that with this query:

```
SELECT t.IND_STATUS
FROM transaction_status_history t
LEFT JOIN transaction_status_history t1 ON t.idt_transaction = t1.idt_transaction
                                            AND t1.IND_STATUS = 'Approved'
WHERE
    t.idt_transaction = 12
    AND (
            (t.IND_STATUS = 'New' AND ISNULL(t1.IND_STATUS,'Approved') = 'Approved')
            OR t.IND_STATUS = 'Rejected'
    )
```